# SQL Query produced by Umbraco app & NHibernate ORM - help!

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, execution-plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ1BhSun

This is a sample of a query that this CMS called "Umbraco 5" runs against its backend DB, which is currently hosted on SQL 2008R2.  This query runs upon or after **login**.  Yeah, don't ask me why such a ridiculously complex query is needed on/just-after login.

It's taking over 30 seconds, which apparently is the magic borderline of the app's query/command-timeout setting when it passes the query down from the data-layer.  And apparently it used to take a bit less than 30 seconds so until now, it hasn't been a "breaking issue".  But of course now that it is, I, the DBA, am being asked to help fix it, despite having almost no control over the application nor the way the query itself is written/constructed (by NHibernate).

Any suggestions for magic index tuning based on the query plan (linked above), that might help this perform better?

Things I've checked/tried:

1. There are existing indexes that **seem** to make perfect sense, based on the join-predicates an so forth.
2. `sp_BlitzIndex` offers no further suggestions for missing indexes.
3. I've tried rebuild/reorg indexes, & keeping stats updated to a ridiculous degree, but none of that helps.

Edit: because the query itself got cut off by the XML dump of the plan, here is the last part of it, starting just before the query cuts off in the pastetheplan link (contextual part in curly-braces, everything after that is what's missing):

```
        {ON this_0_.NodeVersionStatusTypeId=innertype2_}.Id 
    WHERE innerversi1_.NodeId = this_.NodeId 
    ORDER BY this_0_.Date DESC) 
AND this_.NodeId IN ('f3dea406-879b-42fe-be79-a0320098c921','32307dbd-c2ea-41a2-8d12-a052011a012e','613c7c0b-97a5-427a-8dbf-a05400a504ce') 
ORDER BY outerhisto2_.Date ASC
```

Remember, *I didn't write this!*  (Though I did try to tidy up the format just a bit for readers.)

Comment: It looks like you have a pretty nasty Key Lookup! On the NodeVersionStatusHistory table, add the Date column to U5_IDX_NodeVersionStatusHistory_NodeVersionStatusType as an Included column. That may help a bit.

Comment: The suggestion by Erik **did** help a bit, so we're in better shape than before.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik should post an answer for it since it helped a lot.

Comment: @NateJ I would try an index on `dbo.NodeVersionStatusHistory ([Date] DESC, Id, NodeVersionId)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has reached the end of its useful life.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I'd agree with that. :)